# azure unable to delete deployment

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles

I'm new with Azure.

I used publishing from Visual Studio to deploy my project for a month. Today I tried to deploy my project to Staging, waited for 20 minutes "Creating..." status and pressed cancel. But the staging deployment is not deleting for 2 hours - it is still in the "Creating..." status. Hence, the delete button is disabled in the Management Portal, I cannot also republish the deployment. On health status I see:

> WARNING: While one or more of your deployments is suspended, it
>   continues to accrue charges. Please delete the suspended deployment if
>   you no longer wish to be charged for it. For more details visit  .

How to delete or republish the deployment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related with unavailability of Windows Azure Compute.

If you have the same problem, go to Azure service dashboard that is available here:
http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/support/status/servicedashboard.aspx.

NB: If you even see "Performance degradation" status it can also indicate to unavailability of service.

Answer (score 1):

We've experienced this issue on very rare occasions. It is apparently an issue with the fabric when a certain combination of failures happen tearing down an existing role.

To resolve it we've raised a ticket with the Azure Service Desk and they've usually pretty quickly gotten to the bottom of the issue, given the role a quick reset behind the scenes and then you can delete it / redeploy or whatever you were trying to do in the first place.